# Error while trying to find workaround to Java's requirement that cases in switch statements must be final

Tags: java, switch-statement, final

I'm trying to find a workaround to Java's requirement that cases in switch statements must be final. So far, my attempts have failed, and I am unsure as to why this is happening. I would prefer to use a switch statement rather than an if/else unless absolutely necessary.

My goal is to have a switch statement with a case that varies depending on the value of a non-final variable. Java requires that the case be constant.

To get around this requirement, I have tried creating final variables with the value of non-final variables. This way, the final variables can be used as cases while still having the value of a non-final variable.

Assigning a local or an instance variable's value to a final variable causes a compiler error (method test2 for local variables, test3 for instance variables). Why does this occur?

On the other hand, assigning a final variable to a literal constant works perfectly (method test1).

Is there any possible workaround to Java's restriction?

```
class Main {
  private int instance = 0;
  public Main(int i){
      instance = i;
  }
  public void test1(int num){
      final int FINAL = 3;
      switch(num){
          case FINAL:
          System.out.println(FINAL);
          break;
          default:
          System.out.println("nothing");
      }
  }
  // methods test2 and test3 did not compile
  public void test2(int num){
      int locVar = 3;
      final int FINAL = locVar;
      switch(num){
          case FINAL:
          System.out.println(FINAL); // line 20
          break;
          default:
          System.out.println("nothing");
      }
  }
  public void test3(int num){
      final int FINAL = instance;
      switch(num){
          case FINAL:
          System.out.println(FINAL); // line 30
          break;
          default:
          System.out.println("nothing");
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main(3); // instance variable named int instance = 3
    m.test1(3);
    // m.test2(3);
    // m.test3(3);
  }
}
```

Expected output (if this were to work perfectly):

```
3
3
3
```

Error produced: constant expression required at lines 20 and 30

Comment: The switch cases must be compile-time constants. There's no getting around that. If you don't have compile-time constants, just use `if` statements instead.

Comment: It's not that they have to be effectively final. From JLS 14.11: "Every case label has a case constant, which is either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant." You're not going to find a way around that.

Comment: Cases in a switch must be constants - that is “final” values.

Comment: `final` is not enough - a [ConstantExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConstantExpression) is: "*...refer to constant variables (§4.12.4)....*" and "*A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression*"

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find a workaround to Java's requirement that cases in switch statements must be final

Such efforts are a wild goose chase. There is no workaround of this requirement, assuming you wish your case labels to refer to a "variable".

According to [JLS 14.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> Every case label has a case constant, which is either a constant expression or the name of an enum constant

So, it is not even a requirement that the case labels are *final*: it is that they have to be [constant expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), of which constant variables (["a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)) are merely one kind.

A key point about constant variables is that is `final` is necessary, but not sufficient.

The reason why switch cases must be constant is that the compiler generates a table of jumps ([either `tableswitch` or `lookupswitch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10)): in order to do this, it must know all the possible jumps at compile time.

Some languages support non-constant cases in switches (e.g. [golang](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/10), or Kotlin's [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)), but Java does not.

You have to use an alternative control structure (e.g. if/else) if you want to avoid the requirement of constant case labels.